# How to execute a secure query PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','', 'dbname');
if(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "register")){
$username = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'username');
$password = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'password');
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'email');

$stmtInsertUser = $con -> prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_users (username, password, email) values (?, ?, ?)");

$stmtInsertUser -> bind_param($username, $password, $email);

$stmtInsertUser -> execute();
```

}

This is my code and it returns this error

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\xxx\PHPregister.php on line 10
```

Thanks!

Comment: Read [the documentation for bind_param](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) - your arguments are wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of bind_param is a list of what types of inputs are coming in

Per the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php (s is string)

```
$stmtInsertUser -> bind_param('sss',$username, $password, $email);
```

Comment: Yes it does, the full list: i corresponding variable has type integer, d corresponding variable has type double, s corresponding variable has type string, b corresponding variable is a blob and will be sent in packets

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$stmtInsertUser->bind_param('sss',$username, $password, $email);
```